# Generating Sequence Diagrams Using UMLGraph

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram, umlgraph

I am using [UMLGraph](http://www.umlgraph.org/) to generate sequence diagrams. I have a problem using the pic2plot program to generate svg images. It clips the image and parts of the image don't show. This problem is also documented in the [FAQ](http://www.umlgraph.org/faq.html#truncxml):

```
How can I prevent clipped SVG images in sequence diagrams?

This appears to be a limitation of pic2plot. You can work around it, by increasing the width and height values appearing in the SVG XML file that pic2plot generates.
```

However, I have tried but failed to change the width and height in the svg image. I tried modifying the `width="8in" height="8in" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none"` 
 in the svg with no success.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know about how to solve this specific problem with UMLGraph but if you are open to use other similar textual modeling tools, take a look [here](http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml-tools#textual) with more than 10 tools available

Comment: I have been through that list. Thanks Jordi. I like UMLGraph better, but only have the clipping problem.

Comment: MetaUML look nice but I am also failing to generate *.gif *.svg *.png from it. Any ideas?

Comment: For future reference, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1743618/435253 would probably be a more appropriate listing of alternatives. (It has four different open-source, non-UMLGraph sequence diagram generators based on domain-specific languages. One of them, mscgen, even has a GPLv3 JavaScript port.)

Answer (score 0):

Editing the first line of the generated SVG seems to help...

Keeping the first parameter in the viewBox fixed, I scaled the width and the delta between third parameter and first parameter in the viewBox by 1.5 from

```
<svg baseProfile="full" height="19.67in" id="body" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="-0.3800 -0.7325 0.6900 2.4588" width="5.52in" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

to

```
<svg baseProfile="full" height="19.67in" id="body" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="-0.3800 -0.7325 1.035 2.4588" width="8.28in" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

No more clipping for me and looks okay. Your mileage may vary.